# aiogram не видит данные с SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

**Пытаюсь взять из таблицы "users" данные "money", но при выводе на чат, выводит пустую таблицу. Вроде бы в "money" записана "0", но его не видит. Из-за чего так происходит?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**bot.py**

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

db = Database("database.db")

async def on_startup(_):
    print('Bot is online!')

@dp.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
async def start(message : types.Message):  
    if message.chat.type == "private":
        if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
            db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
        
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Добро пожаловать!\nВаш счет: {db.user_money(message.from_user.id)} руб")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

**db.py**

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        
    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))
    
    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))
    
    def user_money(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT 'money' FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchmany(1)
            return result
```

Comment: У вас имя файла db.py и имя базы одинаковы db = Database... Как вы делаете import файла в bot.py?

Comment: Я практикуюсь смотря разные туториалы, там сказано, что при создании таблицы, в проект - Database импортируется через "db = Database("database.db")". Может я ошибаюсь, но правильно ли так импортировать?

Answer (score 0):

Логично было бы в файле bot.py написать import db. Базу назвать как-нибудь иначе base_bot = db.Database("database.db"), например. И тогда обращение к методам base_bot.user_money(message.from_user.id)